Good items for disarming?
I'm building a human ifrit rogue in Pathfinder 2e, and I've taken the Scorching Disarm feat linked here. I'm struggling to find talismans and magic items that assist with athletics checks for disarming, its possible I might not be searching the right way, but does anyone have any suggestions?

Your options are few and far between, so far as items go. You might find more feat support outside of Rogue as well, so I'd suggest you look for some archetype to help.
Some items:

Magnetic Shield: common shield, level 5. If you Shield Block a metal weapon while this shield has been activated, you get a +1 item bonus (not great, and easily outscaled).
Oily Button: a legacy (pre-remaster) uncommon item from an adventure, so not likely to be allowed by every GM. It'll help with your second Disarm in a turn if your first attempt succeeds.
Catching shield rune: it won't work with Scorching Disarm, but it is a circumstance bonus to Disarms done via the shield, and those are pretty rare.

Otherwise, it looks like you're best off just going for any of the many items that straight increase your Athletics skill (e.g. Lifting Belt, Bracers of Strength), and grabbing relevant feats from an archetype (e.g. Monk's Reflective Ripple Stance, Bastion's Disarming Block) or your own class (only Sly Disarm).
